# Cross Compiling Apache For ARM Problems

Tags: apache, arm, ubuntu-14.04, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile Apache for an ARM system using an Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM.  I was able to get all of the required libraries built (PCRE, APR, APR-Util, Libtool) and the configure script will run fine.  However, when I run the make command I receive the following errors.  At this point I am completely lost as what to do to fix this.

```
util.c: In function ‘ap_parse_token_list_strict’:
util.c:1528:14: error: ‘T_HTTP_TOKEN_STOP’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c:1528:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for 
each function it appears in
util.c: In function ‘ap_scan_http_field_content’:
util.c:1602:14: error: ‘T_HTTP_CTRLS’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_scan_http_token’:
util.c:1612:14: error: ‘T_HTTP_TOKEN_STOP’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_scan_vchar_obstext’:
util.c:1622:13: error: ‘T_VCHAR_OBSTEXT’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_find_token’:
util.c:1683:22: error: ‘T_HTTP_TOKEN_STOP’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_escape_logitem’:
util.c:2092:13: error: ‘T_ESCAPE_LOGITEM’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_escape_errorlog_item’:
util.c:2162:13: error: ‘T_ESCAPE_LOGITEM’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)
util.c: In function ‘ap_append_pid’:
util.c:2480:25: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long 
int’, but argument 5 has type ‘__pid_t’ [-Wformat]
make[2]: *** [util.lo] Error 1
```

Here is the script I am using to configure

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH
export ARCH=armv7l
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
export CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld
export LD_LIBRARY=/home/kyle/httpd/srclib/expat/bin
export CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
export CPP=arm-linux-gnueabi-cpp
export STRIP=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
export CC_FOR_BUILD=i686-linux-gnu-gcc
./configure \
    --host=arm-linux-gnueabi \
    --target=arm-linux-gnueabi \
    --prefix=/home/kyle/httpd \
    --build=i686-cross-linux-gnu \
    --with-apr=/home/kyle/httpd/srclib/apr \
    --with-apr-util=/home/kyle/httpd/srclib/apr-util \
    --with-pcre=/home/kyle/httpd/srclib/pcre \
    --with-expat=/home/kyle/httpd/srclib/expat \
    --disable-libtool-lock \
    ac_cv_file__dev_zero=no \
    ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=no \
    apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork=no \
    ap_cv_void_ptr_lt_long=4 \
    ac_cv_sizeof_struct_iovec=1
```

****EDIT: I believe I have found the solution****

The problem was I was copying over the gen_test_char from APR to get around the known bug with it, but this was not the same gen_test_char as in httpd/server.  So a simple workaround is run the make command wait for it to fail because of the gen_test_char being in the wrong format, and then run

```
gcc gen_test_char.c -I"(where ever apr is)/apr/include" -o gen_test_char
```

After this run make again and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

**export your toolchain path**

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1/bin

**---------------------------------------- Steps for pcre-8.43 ----------------------------------------**

```
tar xvjf pcre-8.43.tar.bz2
cd pcre-8.43
./configure --prefix=/mnt/flash2/apache2_server --host=aarch64-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc AR=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar STRIP=aarch64-linux-gnu-strip RANLIB=aarch64-linux-gnu-ranlib 
make
make install DESTDIR=/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server
cd ..
```

**---------------------------------------- Steps for libexpat-R_2_2_9 ----------------------------------------**

```
tar xvzf libexpat-R_2_2_9.tar.gz
cd libexpat-R_2_2_9/expat
./buildconf.sh
./configure --prefix=/mnt/flash2/apache2_server --host=aarch64-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc AR=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar STRIP=aarch64-linux-gnu-strip RANLIB=aarch64-linux-gnu-ranlib 
make
make install DESTDIR=/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server
cd ../..
```

**-------------------------- Steps for httpd-2.4.23(apache2 with apr, apr-util, pcre) --------------------------**

Download apr-1.5.0 and apr-util-1.6.1 library and extract compressed file into

```
httpd-2.4.23/srclib
tar xvzf httpd-2.4.23.tar.gz
tar xvzf apr-1.5.0.tar.gz
tar xvjf apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2
mv apr-1.5.0 httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr
mv apr-util-1.6.1 httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr-util
cd httpd-2.4.23
./configure --prefix=/mnt/flash2/apache2_server --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc CPP=aarch64-linux-gnu-cpp CXX=aarch64-linux-gnu-c++ AR=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar STRIP=aarch64-linux-gnu-strip RANLIB=aarch64-linux-gnu-ranlib --with-included-apr --with-pcre=/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/pcre-8.43/pcre-config --with-expat=/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server/mnt/flash2/apache2_server ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void="no" ap_cv_void_ptr_lt_long=4 ac_cv_file__dev_zero="yes" ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void="yes" apr_cv_process_shared_works="yes" apr_cv_mutex_robust_shared="no" apr_cv_tcp_nodelay_with_cork="yes" ac_cv_sizeof_struct_iovec="8" apr_cv_mutex_recursive="yes" --enable-mpms-shared=all --with-mpm=event
make
```

-------If following error -------

/bin/bash: tools/gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Makefile:137: recipe for target 'include/private/apr_escape_test_char.h' failed

make[1]: *** [include/private/apr_escape_test_char.h] Error 126

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apr-1.5.0'

/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apr-1.5.0/build/apr_rules.mk:118: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

--------Solution-------

```
cd srclib/apr/tools
gcc -Wall -O2 -DCROSS_COMPILE gen_test_char.c -s -o gen_test_char
cd ../../..
make
```

---------If following kind of error --------

/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/httpd-2.4.23/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc  -g -O2      -L/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server/mnt/flash2/apache2_server/lib   -o gen_test_char -L/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server/mnt/flash2/apache2_server/lib gen_test_char.lo 

./gen_test_char > test_char.h

/bin/bash: ./gen_test_char: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Makefile:36: recipe for target 'test_char.h' failed

make[2]: *** [test_char.h] Error 126

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/httpd-2.4.23/server'

/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/httpd-2.4.23/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/httpd-2.4.23/server'

/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/httpd-2.4.23/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

--------Solution-------

```
cd server 
gcc gen_test_char.c -I./../srclib/apr/include/ -o gen_test_char
cd ..
make
make install DESTDIR=/home/ahmcpu2176/Downloads/apache2_server
cd ..
tar cvzf apache2_server.tar.gz apache2_server
```